# DBMS_XMLQUERY vs DBMS_XMLGEN: Any replacement for DBMS_XMLQUERY.seterrortag(sqlcontext, 'Any_Tag_Name')

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle12c, dbms-xmlgen

Since Oracle version is upgraded. We have to replace all the existing `DBMS_XMLQUERY`  functions to `DBMS_XMLGEN`. There is one function `DBMS_XMLQUERY.seterrortag(sqlcontext, 'Any_Tag_Name')`. We didn't get any replacement for this tag in XMLGEN. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: We get a fix by using xmlgen instead of dbms_xmlgen, so above tag looks like : XMLGEN.seterrortag('Any_Tag_Name'). Here we don't need to use sqlcontext

Answer (score 0):

We get a fix by using xmlgen instead of dbms_xmlgen, so above tag looks like : XMLGEN.seterrortag('Any_Tag_Name'). Here we don't need to use sqlcontext